# Using fscanf to read into an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct, scanf

This is a function that I am using to read from a file into an array of structs. All of the "printf" statements are for debugging purposes.

```
int read_processes(process list[], int count) { 
  char file_name[80];
  FILE *file;
  printf ("Enter file name: ");
  scanf ("%s", file_name);

  //executes block if file is opened properly
  if ((file = fopen(file_name, "r")) != NULL) {
    printf("before fscanf\n");
    while (!feof(file) && (count < 100)) {    
      printf ("Middle of fscanf\n");
      fscanf(file, "%s", list[count].name);
      printf ("Name is %s\n", list[count].name);
      fscanf(file, "%d", list[count].arrival_time);
      printf ("Arrival time is %d\n", list[count].arrival_time);
      fscanf(file, "%d\n", list[count].execution_time);
      printf ("Execution time is %d\n", list[count].execution_time);
      fscanf(file, "%d\n", list[count].priority);
      printf ("Priority is %d\n", list[count].priority);
      count++;          //count will be number of items in array
      printf("after fscanf %d\n", count);
   }
    printf ("after EOF\n");
    fclose(file);
    return 1;
  }
  //returns zero if file is not opened properly
  else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

The function stops after the "printf ("Name is %s\n", list[count].name);" line. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `fscanf(file, "%d", list[count].arrival_time);` Add `&` --> `fscanf(file, "%d", &list[count].arrival_time);`

Comment: And Read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks. Why was '&' not needed for list[count].name?

Comment: The Array itself represents its first address. (I guess that is an array of `char`.)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That makes sense. Awesome, i appreciate it.